# Stack Exchange keeps creating new accounts

Tags: support, bug, deleted-accounts, multiple-accounts

I am not sure if this is designed this way or if I am doing something wrong. In order for me to even post this question, it asked me to "Confirm new account" and at this point I already know that it is creating yet another account for me. If I try to Cancel, it just refreshes the page still asking me to confirm my new account.

So I started with Stack Overflow. I had an account on there for over a year that I just recently started using and participating with.  The account link used to be : https://stackoverflow.com/users/9542490/victoria-stampfli
I had some reputation and badges on there. Until one day, when I downloaded the Stack Exchange app, logged in with my Stack Overflow account and decided to check out other sites on Stack Exchange. The first comment I made on another site gave me the all-famous "Confirm your new account" page with no ability to cancel in order to proceed. So when I confirmed, I got new url  (https://stackexchange.com/users/13212883/user194995) with new account, no reputation, all my history is gone.  Except in the top menu, if you go up there you can still see all the notifications of my previously earned badges etc. Though no badges on the profile. When I try to go to the old url for my original account, it says :"Page not found". 
So I contacted support by using the sites form twice now and have not heard anything back. Now I am on here asking this question trying to figure out how this whole thing works, and it asked my to "confirm my new account" yet again just to ask this question. I am quite confused with all these accounts. I would really like to have my original account back.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you used to post spam?

Comment: what do you mean? I posted questions and answers and comments, like everyone else. what would be considered spam?

Comment: Spam is advertisements for your products or services. That's probably the #1 reason why someone would lose their account.

Comment: nope, no advertisements.It happened the moment I posted the comment on the other stackExchange site.

Comment: Did you request account deletion at any time?

Comment: nope, not at all. I did change my name right before that from Victoria Stampfli to Vic. Not sure if that did anything.

Comment: At least your SO account appears to no longer exist...

Comment: @Luuklag, That is what it looks like. I wonder why. Although, my emails are still all there, and all my notifications are all there , now under this account. And.... someone just sent me an email on StackOverflow yesterday with job posting, addressing me as Victoria. My new account doesn't show my name. My old one did. Does this mean that somehow people can still see the old account? This is so confusing.

Comment: I think you are better off using the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page, to contact the community team and have them look into it. All we average Joe users can do is speculate. The community team are the ones that can actually investigate what really happened. Did you somehow trigger a merge of your different accounts, did your previous account get deleted for reasons of moderation, did you somehow self-delete your previous account or who knows what...

Comment: I did! I submitted my problem twice on the Contact form on Stack Overflow. Once last Friday and once Monday morning. I have not heard anything yet. I guess it won't hurt to submit one on Stack Exchange as well.

Comment: possible dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223911/i-probably-shouldnt-have-deleted-my-account-how-can-i-get-it-back/223912#223912

Comment: It is not rare for the community team to take more then a week to respond, they tend to be busy.

Comment: oh ok, I will wait then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same confusion... but now I guess I know what's happening.

Stack exchange does create new accounts for each site, but does not delete the old accounts.

Try clicking on your **profile picture** shown on the top, followed by **Network profile**. Then, click on **accounts**.
This will show all the accounts you have signed up to.
Something like this:
[image: Accounts i have signed up for from the beginning]

If it doesn't show your account even there, then it's a problem. Reputation and badges are considered separately for different accounts in this forum.

Comment: No need to go to the network profile to see the accounts, they're also listed in our [Profile tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile), to the left under "Communities". (It's showing up to 5, ordered by reputation)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Oh yes! Thanks for the comment. Noticed it just now. It's showing the same on my account too.